# Eclim disregards native library path when launching Java program

Tags: java, vim, lwjgl, eclim

I'm using [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) and Vim for Java development. I'm trying to set up the [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) so I can program OpenGL stuff with Java. So, when I run :Java from Vim to run a lwjgl test program I made, Eclim gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
```

Even though I generated this [.classpath file](https://gist.github.com/4409676) with Eclipse which clearly contains the path to the native lwjgl libraries for my Linux box.

This is how Eclipse would run my program:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/share/lwjgl/native/linux -classpath /home/alex/code/java/OpenGL/bin:/usr/share/lwjgl/jar/lwjgl.jar Test
```

I have a feeling that Eclim is omitting:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/share/lwjgl/native/linux
```

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNC77NzmIts&feature=player_embedded) demonstrating the situation (and my test program).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It's an Eclim setting.

```
:EclimSettings
zR (to unfold the settings)
```

find org.eclim.java.run.jvmargs and add inside [ ]:

```
 "-Djava.library.path=/usr/share/lwjgl/native/linux"
```